# Changing the 'From' email address, and adding multiple email addresses to the 'To' in Mail Merge sent through Outlook

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have to do a lot of campaigns for work, sending lots of emails with almost the same thing to batches of people. I've been using mail merge with word, an excel spreadsheet and outlook. The problem is I can only send to one user per email, and it defaults to send from my email rather than the shared inbox that I'd prefer to send it from.

Goal: 
to add multiple email addresses per email in the 'To' field.
to change the 'From' email address to something other than my default.

What I've tried so far:
Adding multiple email in the 'To' field of the spreadsheet with ',' or ';' between them. '.' causes error, and ';' comes up with can't find the email address (as it searches for all of them as one address).

I don't have access to the password of my works shared inboxes, so I am not able to login under them and change my default as others have suggested.

I'm guessing there is a way to do this in VBA, I just need some help.

Cheers

Comment: A very good guide to work with outlook in vba: https://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Outlook_external_en.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Recipients` property of mail items to modify the To, CC or BCC fields. For example:

```
Sub CreateStatusReportToBoss() 

 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 

 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)  
 Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add("Eugene")  
 myItem.Subject = "Status Report"  
 myItem.Display 

End Sub
```